# APK has been signed with an insecure key size while uploading Google play store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, release

I have generated APK with release certificate in android studio. While uploading Intune Google play store getting following error,
**APK has been signed with an insecure key size.**

Please guide me to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more context so I can help you. Maybe the screenshots of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received the same error. So i try the below method. I have tried in mac. Now my error is gone. use the below way to solve.

keytool.exe -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias TicTacToe -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem you have exactly without more context, but based on what is provided this is what Google says about [App signing key requirements](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en#zippy=%2Capp-signing-key-requirements).

**App signing key requirements:**

```
When you use a Google-generated key, Google automatically generates a
cryptographically strong RSA key that’s 4096 bits.
If you choose to upload your own app signing key,
then it must be an RSA key that’s 2048 bits or more.
```

**Upload key requirements:**

```
Must be an RSA key that's 2048 bits or more.
```

Comment: I have create keystore in android studio. As per my application requirement I’m signing apk in command line using same keystore but while uploading Getting this error APK has been signed with an insecure key size.

Comment: Unless you provide more context including screenshot of the error, I can suggest you to try two things. First, try creating another key and sign your application with the new key and upload to play console. Second, sign your application through android studio: Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APK; and upload your application to Play console